# Input function within or outside function

Tags: python

I've recently started learning how to code in python. I wanted to know if there is a norm or specific rule for the position of statements while using functions.

eg:

```
def example(x):
    y = 7
    print("Default value is", y)
    print("Value entered is", x)


a = int(input("Enter a value: "))
example(a)
```

Would it be better to move the input statement inside the function? Will this pose any problems in more complex programs?

Comment: You have a typo with a missing right parenthesis. Fix: `a = int(input("Enter a value: "))`

Comment: This question is a bit too subjective for StackOverflow. There is nothing inherently wrong with either approach. Any answer here would just be an opinion. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Beside the point, but `input()` is a function, not a statement. You also don't have any declarations in this code. Maybe you're talking about the assignment statement `a = ...`

Comment: @Andrew Agreed. I was going to post an answer saying "outside, for better flexibility", but on second thought, it depends on the context, and this example code is really vague.

Comment: Well, since you asked about *norms*, it is not typical to provide values to `input`. Usually people would just type argument values in a function call `example(5)`. The only thing `input` might add is allow multiple prompts throughout one function call. I'm guessing that in your case, `input` is being used in a programming tutorial so you can run a program without having to learn much about functions first.

Comment: ah right my bad. I'm still new to the terminology.

Answer (score 2):

In larger programs, pretty much everything will be in functions (or methods, which are a kind of function). The only code at the top level will be a couple of lines to call the first function (often called `main`).

The question then is whether to put the `input` into the same function, or into separate functions. That's a more general question of how to organise code, how large or small to make the functions and how to separate concerns.

For `input()` in particular, it's probably better to put it in a separate function from the calculation; that way, you will be able to use the same calculation functions (a) with user-supplied input; (b) with values coming from elsewhere in the program; and, importantly (c) from tests.

Similarly, probably separate the output from the calculation; again, you'll then be able to (a) print it out; (b) further process it or write it to file, database, etc; and (c) check it in tests.

That way, you'll have three functions, each with a separate concern: one to get the input from the user and convert it to `int`; a second one to do whatever calculation is required; and a third one to format up the result neatly and print it for the user.

Answer (score 1):

If the result of input statement will only be used inside one function, then moving the statement into that function might be better in the future when your code becomes more complex

Comment: When the code becomes more complex, the input is likely to instead come from a file or another function or somewhere else, so it's more likely to need to be a function parameter? If not always then at least some of the time, eg. for tests?